# Destructing an R object

Tags: r

Is there any destructor in R (like destructors in C++ or "__ del __" in Python) to do some custom steps before deleting an object?

I have tried using remove() or rm(), but they just delete the variable from the environment. I would like to call a function every time the object is deleted.

Comment: `rm()` followed by `gc()` is all you have for removal.  You can create an object, though, and the object can have a 'finalizer' method.  The R6 system is a good compromise between features and complexity.

Comment: Presumably there is a broader motivation why you want a function to be called when an object is removed, and if you can describe that in your question people might be able to suggest alternative approaches idiomatic to R. (Potential xy problem.)

Comment: You can use [`on.exit`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/on.exit.html) to perform cleanup operations. This is the canonical equivalent to destructors in R. (There’s also [`reg.finalizer`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/reg.finalizer.html) but this is **very** rarely the right solution in R. I’ve **never** used it, and I write some pretty gnarly R code.)

Comment: Yes `on.exit()` helps at the local scope level though it is not tied to a particular object.

Answer (score 1):

This is not good code and there is probably a better way to do what you want if you can describe it more broadly. Here I am creating a new remove function which does some steps before it calls the normal `rm` function. You could presumably tweak it if you want different steps for different sorts of objects, or objects with particular names.

```
rm2 <- function(x) {
  x_nm <- as.character(substitute(x))
  message("current value of ", x_nm, " is ", x)
  message("deleting ", x_nm)
  rm(list = x_nm, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

a <- "hello"
rm2(a)
# current value of a is hello
# deleting a
# [now a is gone from the global environment]
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want special clean up to happen when the object is deleted.

This is rarely necessary because the garbage collector normally does it for you.  Where you need it is when dealing with external libs that allocate resources outside of r.  Use the `reg.finalizer` function to register a function to be called when an object is garbage collected.